# How can I get Total Commander to recognize Cygwin symlinks?

Tags: cygwin, symbolic-link, total-commander, ln

I *love* Total Commander. I *love* Cygwin. But they are not always friends. One thing that bugs me, is the way symlinks work in Cygwin. Suppose I do this:

```
$ ln -s my/path/to/nirvana budhism
```

And then do: (because cygwin won't let me view `budhism`)

```
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\projects>type budhism
!<symlink> ■m y / p a t h / t o / n i r v a n a
C:\projects>
```

See? I guess a windows `.lnk` file might have also done the trick, but no, we have a special file here. Wouldn't it be nice if Total Commander would recognize that file as the file/folder it points to?

Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: By the way on "viewing" symlinks, you might want to check out `file budhism` or `stat budhism`, if you want to get info about a symlink

Comment: We all love Total Commander!

Comment: This isn't just a Cygwin symlink problem. [Total Commander can't copy symlinks created with the Windows native `mklink` command](http://i.imgur.com/pwJPzxf.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to say, but I believe you can't do it, at least not in a reliable way. This is about *Windows* vs. *symbolic links* vs. *Cygwin*.

Symbolic links as they work in Linux are on filesystem level. The fact that they work with Cygwin is just that it's able to "lie to itself" with help of these special files you mention.

Although there is similar facility on Windows/NTFS, which might suggest that Cygwin could make use of them, there are so many drawbacks (they work differently on XP than on Vista+; they don't work at all with FAT partitions...) that it's reasonable that Cygwin developers chose not to use them for this simulation.

- on Vista+ you can use `mklink` or `mklink /d` to create symlink to file or directory, respectively
- on XP you can create *junction*, (which is like symlink but it only works for directories), but you have to use external tool for that (e.g. Sysinternals' `junction.exe`)

While I could imagine either a package for Cygwin that would make it use different technique (probably some hardcore black magic), I would be surprised if in the small overlap of Cygwin/TC users there was a developer willing to do such thing.

I also *love* TC. When I'm on Windows, it's my both hands. But with Cygwin, best advice I can give you are:

- learn to use some Linux shell—e.g bash works on pretty every OS a mortal can find on Earth
- learn to use Midnight Commander—a popular console file manager. It operates on the same basis as TC and is almost as ubiquitous as bash

As a bonus, these are both console things, so you'll be able to use them under remote ssh connection, which is a must if you ever get work with remote UNIX-like machine.

Comment: sorry for accepting your answer so late. I had actually totally forgotten about it. I just found it, when googling for this problem. And then, just before I closed the browser tab, I went, wait-a-minute: Did I edit the question at some time or why is my name there? NO WAY! That is actually a question my past-self asked... So TIL, I'm still no smarter than I was more than a half a year ago. Way to go, Daren. You are really making progress!

Comment: For future reference: [Cygwin can be told to create native symlinks](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) by using `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict`.